# Change Magento Iphone theme colours

Tags: theme, iphone

I have introduced the Magento Iphone theme and successfully changed the header logo.

I cannot find anywhere how to change or what controls the orange background colour in the header and footer;

Header - where the cart, search and menu appears

Footer - where the links appear

Footer - where the copyright appears

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: I have resolved the solution for the Header -where the cart, search and menu appears.                                   Change background colour, find the following in theme CSS:                                                      body > header .menu-wrapper { and add background:#shade;

Comment: Also, if you add background to: body > footer this changes the newsletter background shade but I cannot find how to change the links above and copyright below???

Comment: This question is not related to a Magento issue, but is simply in reference to theme customization/css - all of which is highly documented (http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf). Flagging for closure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to remove the orange background colors in the Iphone theme;

Header - where the cart, search and menu appears
body > header .menu-wrapper { background-color:#your color; }

Footer - where the subscribe box appears
body > footer { background-color:#your color; }

Footer - where the links & copyright appears
body > address.copyright { background-color:#your color; }

Answer (score -1):

Doing the above, suggested by Dan:

"Here is how to remove the orange background colors in the Iphone theme;

Header - where the cart, search and menu appears body > header .menu-wrapper { background-color:#your color; }

Footer - where the subscribe box appears body > footer { background-color:#your color; }

Footer - where the links & copyright appears body > address.copyright { background-color:#your color; }"

did not help completely -- some areas still remained orange.

I did the following: in /skin/frontend/default/mobile/css/ in all .css files searched for #e76212 color, and replaced it with my own color number.

Only after doing so, I got rid of the default orange color completely, and replaced it with mine.